# Add items to menu in webworks app

Tags: blackberry-webworks

I was wondering how I would go about adding items to the menu that appears when the blackberry button http://jennontech.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/blackberry-logo.jpg is clicked. Thanks to anyone who can help. Btw, I am making an app for blackberry 7, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to approach this is to have a look at the menu sample for WebWorks available at http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Adding-Menu-Items-using-the-BlackBerry-WebWorks-SDK/ta-p/516885

If you want to understand deeper the API this is the page you should look at:
https://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/html5/apis/blackberry.ui.menu.html

A quick overview is:
1. you create the menu item

```
var reloadButton = new blackberry.ui.menu.MenuItem(false, 0, "Refresh", reloadPage);
```

2. you add the reloadButton item menu to the context menu

```
blackberry.ui.menu.clearMenuItems();
blackberry.ui.menu.addMenuItem(reloadButton);
```

That's it! You can optionally specify which menu item is the default one with

```
blackberry.ui.menu.setDefaultMenuItem(reloadButton);
```

Check out the API page for more details.

As a reminder, the ideal place to get the BlackBerry experts support for your queries is the BlackBerry forum http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/bd-p/browser_dev